# Modal Boostrap não é exibido

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho um formulário que estou tentando implementar um modal que confirme o submit deste formulário, porém ele só aparece quando eu não digito os campos obrigatórios, se eu digito os campos obrigatórios ele vai direto para o action

se alguem puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito

código html

```
     <form id="myForm" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" data-toggle="modal" method="POST" action="../Controllers/fecharLocacao.php">

              <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Chegada<span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <input type="datetime-local" id="last-name" name="chegada" required="required"  class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                    </div>

                    <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Comb. Chegada<span class="required">*</span>
                      </label>
                      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <select class="form-control" name="combchegada">
                                  <option value="1/10">1/10</option>
                                  <option value="2/10">2/10</option>
                                  <option value="3/10">3/10</option>
                                  <option value="4/10">4/10</option>
                                  <option value="5/10">5/10</option>
                                  <option value="6/10">6/10</option>
                                  <option value="7/10">7/10</option>
                                  <option value="8/10">8/10</option>
                                  <option value="9/10">9/10</option>
                                  <option value="10/10">10/10</option>
                          </select>
                    </div>

                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Lavagem<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="last-name" name="lavagem"  class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

              </div>


              <div class="form-group">


                  <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name"> Taxa Seguro<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="last-name" name="txseguro"  class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Taxa Aeroporto<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="last-name" name="txaeroport"   class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Lucro cessante<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="last-name" name="lucrocess"   class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Reembolso Despachante<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" step="any" id="last-name" name="redesp"  class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">

                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Observações
                </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="last-name" name="obs" class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>


                <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="last-name">Km Chegada<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="number" id="last-name" name="kmchegada" required="required"  class="form-control col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                  </div>

                  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $resultado->id; ?>">

              </div>

                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                  <a href="locacoes.php"><button class="btn btn-round btn-danger" type="button">Cancelar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>
              <button class="btn btn-round btn-warning" type="reset">Resetar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Fechar Contrato <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span></button>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </form>
```

Modal

```
                  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <form id="submitMyModal">



                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button for="submitMyModal" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "#submitMyModal" ).submit(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Desde ja agradeço a ajuda de qualquer pessoa obrigado

Comment: Já que você não faz a submissão do formulário, por que não muda o botão de submit para button normal? Assim não precisará do preventDefault

Comment: Anderson eu quero fazer a sumissão do formulário

Comment: Então o mesmo botão que submete o formulário deveria abrir o modal? Isto é, se está submetendo o formulário, é esperado que ele vá para o action. Se quer abrir o modal antes disso, precisa separar as coisas.

Comment: Não entendi como separar, mas obrigado por tentar ajudar abraço

Comment: Comece fazendo o botão **apenas** abrir o modal, sem submeter o formulário.

Comment: Certo vc podia me mostrar, sabe eu não sou gênio em programação e estou iniciando se puder me falar onde apago e onde eu mexo em que parte do código agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Um botão do tipo "submit" faz a submissão, mas do tipo "button" não.

Comment: Anderson deu certo o modal está aparecendo sem problemas, o único problema agora é que se eu clicar no button do modal ele não vai pra o action

Comment: O modal está dentro do form que vc quer enviar?

Comment: Não... desculpa aí pessoal sou um programador novato tenham paciência

Comment: Estou vendo pelo código que vc postou que o modal está dentro de algum form. Que form é esse? Tem 2 forms na página?

Comment: O seu modal possui um formulário que parece não ter utilidade alguma. Remove ele e deixe o seu modal dentro do seu formulário original, assim um botão submit dentro do modal submitará para o action desejado.

Comment: Você deveria marcar as repostas que resolveram seu problema como aceita, andei vendo outras perguntas suas e em nenhuma delas foi marcada como aceita. Veja como marcar uma resposta como aceita em https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx7Ts.png e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Answer (score 0):

> É possível fazer com que um botão do modal submeta o formulário, porém é necessário fazer validação dos campos com a propriedade `required` caso contrario o botão do modal vai submeter o formulário desprezando as propriedades `required` dos campos. Fiz uso do plugin `jquery.validate`

**No seu formulário, troque essa linha** (responsável por abrir o modal)

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Fechar Contrato <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span></button>
```

**por esta linha**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-round btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Fechar Contrato <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

> as alterações feitas foram:

- retirado no final da linha `</span></button>` que estava repetido
- retirado  `data-target="#myModal"`

**O modal**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="btnSubmit" for="submitMyModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> alterações feitas no modal:

- retirado o form
- foi colocado um `id="btnSubmit"` no button `Save changes`

  ```
   <button id="btnSubmit" for="submitMyModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  ```

**Coloque esse script na Head do seu documento**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            chegada: "required",
            combchegada: "required",
            lavagem: "required",
            txseguro: "required",
            txaeroport: "required",
            redesp: "required",
            kmchegada: "required",
        },
            messages: {
            chegada: "requerido",
            combchegada: "requerido",
            lavagem: "requerido",
            txseguro: "requerido",
            txaeroport: "requerido",
            redesp: "requerido",
            kmchegada: "requerido",
        },
    
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                form.submit();
           });
        }
    });
});
```

**bibliotecas requeridas**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```